# Searching columns in a csv file

Tags: python, csv, row, col

I have a program which generates a random name and a random question (both independent from eachother). I have created a function called `QuestionGenerator()` , and it should search through the second column of a csv file and write all the values to the array.

```
def QuestionGenerator():
    questionlist_file = open('StudentNames&Questions.csv')
    reader = csv.reader(questionlist_file)
    rownum=0
    array=[]
    for row in reader:
        array.append(row)
        rownum=rownum+1
    i = random.randint(0,3)
    question = array[0,1]
    return question
```

Currently it writes all the values in the file to the array, and not only the second column (question column). So the array should contain the following values

```
array = ["Consequences of Devolution", "Sources of the Constitution"...."Reasons for a democratic deficit"]
```

[image: Here is a picture of the csv file]

Please note the csv file is an excel spreadsheet saves as a .csv

Comment: Can you please post your CSV file and the expected output?

Comment: I've shown a picture of the contents of the csv file. Thats all thats needed I assume? Will update will the expected outcome.

Comment: This is just a helpful note: if you are doing a lot of work with csv files, you probably want to check out Pandas for working with your data in Python. Pandas has a great data structure called a `DataFrame` which is basically a spreadsheet in Python with rows and columns. Pandas has many utilities for working with csv files and manipulating `DataFrames`. Here is the [quick-start guide](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/10min.html) to Pandas. Hope this may be of some use!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html) might be easier for reading in csv files into a `DataFrame`, but if you want to go with `csv`:

Each row that you read in `array.append(row)` has two columns. To get only the second column, modify the code to read `array.append(row[1])` to subset to the correct column.

The `array` will actually be a list of questions, and to get a random question, you will need to select only one element from the list:

`i = random.randint(1,3)
 question = array[i]`

Notice that i should be between 1 and the number of questions because the first entry in `array` will be "questions", the name of the column. To accomplish this, we can use `i = random.randint(1, len(array) - 1)` which can handle different numbers of questions.

Complete working code is:

```
def QuestionGenerator():
    questionlist_file = open('StudentNames&Questions.csv')
    reader = csv.reader(questionlist_file)
    rownum=0
    array=[]
    for row in reader:

        # Check to make sure the question cell is not blank
        if row[1] != '':

            # Add only the second column to list
            array.append(row[1])
            rownum=rownum+1

    # Select a random question from the list
    i = random.randint(1,len(array) - 1)
    question = array[i]

    return question
```

Comment: This has posed a new problem actually. The for loop keeps looping however many times the largest column is. So if column 1 is 15 values long, and column 2 is only 7 values long, column 2 will loop 15 times. This results in blank spaces occuring in my array. Any ideas how to fix? Code is identical to this one ^

Comment: You can use an `if` statement to not add the blank question cells to your list. I have modified my answer to reflect this.

Answer (score 1):

Your code reads an entire row and saves the value to the array. You could look into using either pandas or CSV reader for saving only targeted columns.

If using pandas, the structure would look something like this:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv(csv_file)
column_of_interest = df.name_of_column #or df['name_of_column']
```

Using CSV library:

```
included_cols = [2]
for row in reader:
    column_of_interest = list(row[i] for i in included_cols) #included_cols could be a list or single value
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Sorry I am a little confused. I would like to use the CSV library, however what does included_cols mean? Where would i define the necesary column to be read and written (to the array)

Comment: Included columns will be like 'included_cols = [2]' since you are only looking to store column 2. If you have a CSV file with more columns, you could include all other desired column numbers. Please let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: Okay i understand. Thanks!